# Making log4j aware of changes in the configuration at runtime

Tags: configuration, runtime, log4j

I wonder if there is a non-programatical way of making log4j aware of changes on the configuration at runtime. I know I can use

```
static {
  PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch("log4j.properties", 100);
}
```

at some useful place to watch a property file for changes, but I would prefer an option within the property file itself, to tell log4j watch for changes. Are there any ?

Comment: Thanks for asking this, as the question itself helped me fix my problem.

Comment: You're welcome :) In the meantime, i switched to slf4j + logback, which offers everything I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j has some [JMX capabilities](http://ajava.org/online/log4j-1.2.15-api/org/apache/log4j/jmx/package-summary.html) which means you can adjust some features dynamically (particularly filtering on level).

Howeever I don't believe you can do much more than that. Appenders have no concept of a lifecycle, which they'd likely need to be able to reliably open/close resources upon reconfiguration.